# User Profile Variables in Google Workspace Signatures

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, google-workspace

I'm trying to create an organisation wide signature for a company that uses Google Workspace as their email host.

My key issue is that i'd like to deploy one signature across the whole organisation and have the system fill in the user's data on their respective signature.

I see this is possible in Office 365, even without interacting with their API directly and simply adding it in as a mail rule. I can't seem to find the same feature on Google Workspace.

In O365 i'd need to set up a signature with the following design in HTML:

%%firstname%% %%lastname%%
%%job title%%

---

My Company Name

etc etc.

Surely Google has an alternative? It would be even better if I could get it to forcibly append the signature on the bottom of all outgoing messages, so the client doesn't even see their signature, and there's consistency across the board.

Anyone else come into this issue? I'm astounded that this seems to be such a basic thing that i'm either being an idiot and missing (entirely possible) or isn't supported.

I've been looking at the following example https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/alias_and_signature_settings which doesn't seem to offer an answer as to what the variables that you can call from user profiles are.

Comment: whats wrong with [managing_signatures](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/alias_and_signature_settings#managing_signatures)?

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo That's the guide I've been using but it doesn't say anything about user's profile attributes variables? By the looks of it, i'd have to do everyone's signatures individually/manually.

Comment: Well yes you would need to save each user one at a time.  Normally I just use a service account and then go though each user one by one setting up their signature.